# How to print out duplicate arrays only once

Tags: java, arrays, printf

So I have to count how many times the number entered by the user and output that display back to the user. I created an array with a for loop to count the number of occurrences. However, I am stuck on how to print the information in the correct format. When I print my array it will print all the number, even the duplicates. In the example, we are supposed to print the example without the duplicates. I'm a little lost on where to go from here to get that done. A little guidance with the direction would be great!

Correct output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AURm9.jpg

My current output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTeOy.jpg

I tried making another array to take in the duplicates and even try to remove that array but had no luck so far.

```
int[] num = new int[7];
       int[] totalCount = new int[7];
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: ");
        for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
            num[i] = kb.nextInt();

            if(num[i] == 0)
                break;
        }


        for(int j=0; j<num.length; j++){
            for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
                if(num[j] == num[i]){
                    totalCount[j]++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<num.length; k++){
             System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n",num[k], totalCount[k]);

        }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use classes from the Java API, for example the `Set` class?

Comment: Your inner for loop should start with j+1 not 0

Comment: @markspace yes we can and that is what I was looking to do but I didn't know what I need for the import to get the correct classes to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the printing simply check if the number was printed before:

```
    for(int j=0; j<num.length; j++){
        boolean shouldPrint = true;
        for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
            if(num[j] == num[i]){
                shouldPrint = false;
            }
        }
        if (shouldPrint == true) {
             System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n",num[k], totalCount[k]);
        }
    }
```

And that way the second element won't be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however even after making the changes that you suggested, the outcome is still the same.

https://imgur.com/l2bPrur

Comment: Oh, you are correct I can see there is a bug now, sorry. 5 min I'll fix it.

Comment: no problem, thanks for the help. Been stuck on it for awhile now

Comment: Fixed, just checking in the elements before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use java8 and streams, `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting` can be used to map the respective elements to their counts.

```
int[] num = new int[7];
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: ");
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    num[i] = kb.nextInt();
    if(num[i] == 0)
        break;
}

Map<Integer, Long>  = Arrays.stream(num)
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.counting()));

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n",entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: And the imports used here are,
`import java.util.Arrays;`
`import java.util.Map;`
`import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 or higher:

```
Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.counting()))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time(s)\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Output:

```
1 occurs 2 time(s)
2 occurs 3 time(s)
3 occurs 2 time(s)
4 occurs 1 time(s)
5 occurs 1 time(s)
```